# How to group PFObjects ? Parse / Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

Hi I'm trying to group `PFObjects`.
For example, consider a **messaging application**.

How can I group by the username of incoming and outgoing messages?

Here is what I'm having:

```
var messages = [PFObject]()

func loadMessages() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Messages")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current()!)
    query.includeKey("user")
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error == nil {

            for object in objects! {
                self.messages.append(object)
            }

        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no built in function for it, you have to do it by yourself, for example when you want to decide whether the image for that Message should be as Incomming or Outgoing...

```
for object in messages {
   if object["user_id"] as PFUser == PFUser.currentUser() {
       //the message is from the same User, set what you need
       //user_id is a column name in Messages as a pointer to User class class
   } else {
       // message was not send from currentUser
   }
}
```